# You'll miss me versus I'll miss you

Tags: traduction, ambiguïté

> Vous allez tous me manquer!

I thought this sentence would mean "you'll all miss me", but apparently it means "i'll miss you all". Now, looking back to it, it seems rather ambiguous...

Does this ambiguity exist? If not, how does the construction leads us to one interpretation instead of the other?

Answer (score 3):

No ambiguity, we just use opposite ways to express this feeling with *manquer*:

- I'll miss you all: *Vous allez tous me manquer*.
- You'll all miss me: *Je vais vous manquer à tous*.

If you translate *miss* as *regretter*, the order would be the same:

- I'll miss you all: *Je vais tous vous regretter*.
- You'll all miss me: *Vous allez tous me regretter*.